# Update excel cells from sql

Tags: excel, vba

Morning everyone,

I have done quite some research but can't seem to be able to find a way to update my Excel cells with data from a SQL table.  For example, in my Excel file I have the following:

ID     Name
1      A
2      B
3      C

and in my sql table, I have a table called myTable and it has the exact format but it might have new and updated values throughout the day and I wanted to update Excel file accordingly.

ID     Name
1      AA
2      B
3      C
4      D
5      E

Any suggestion as how this can be done from the Excel front end?

Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what type of sql server you are using. One quick way to automate your actions is by using the record button in the developer tab. You can start recording a macro, then import data from a sql server (in the data tab). Once all done, look in the module you just created and debug it for standard purpose.

Good day,

Jonathan.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  Will give that a try.

Comment: Answering these types of broad questions are outside the scope of SO. Although I agree it's a generally useful answer in a way, it's more of a tutorial and outside the scope of SO. See [answer] for more.